# Need to combine and get results

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to do the following:

I want to minus the amount of RMAs from Sales:

This is the query I did for Sales:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS PRODUCT_SALES_NUMBER, Orders.SKU AS PRODUCT_SKU, Orders.Description AS PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION
FROM Orders
GROUP BY PRODUCT_SKU
ORDER BY PRODUCT_SALES_NUMBER DESC 
LIMIT 9;
```

This is the one I did for RMAs:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS RETURNED_AMOUNT, Orders.SKU AS PRODUCT_SKU, Orders.Description AS PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION
FROM Orders INNER JOIN RMA ON Orders.OrderID = RMA.OrderID
WHERE UPPER(Status) = "COMPLETE"
GROUP BY PRODUCT_SKU
ORDER BY RETURNED_AMOUNT DESC
LIMIT 9;
```

I would like to take the results (let's say 5000 sales and 3000 rma) and return a formatted result.

Can you please help?
Thanks!!

Comment: Join the two queries on the `PRODUCT_SKU` column.

Comment: it is not guaranteed that both tables contains the same PRODUCT_SKU so comparing ist somewhat difficult

Comment: How would I use PRODUCT_SKU?  I'm new to sql.  It took a while for me to get here. sorry..

Comment: When yoi prodce some hundred orders, you will find thqat both queries can return different when you sort it like that

Comment: These are the tables: 
mysql> DESCRIBE RMA;
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| RMAID   | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| OrderID | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| Step    | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Status  | varchar(15) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Reason  | varchar(15) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: The other table:
mysql> Describe Orders;
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| OrderID     | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| CustomerID  | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| SKU         | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Description | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)

Comment: please edit your question when you have new information, never comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can  jojn both subqueries, only the second can't contain an ORDER VY or LIMIT, because teh first subquery defines the PRODUCT_SKU that are choosen to be in the result set.

```
SELECT
PRODUCT_SALES_NUMBER - RETURNED_AMOUNT, ord1.PRODUCT_SKU, ord1.PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION
FROM
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS PRODUCT_SALES_NUMBER, Orders.SKU AS PRODUCT_SKU, Orders.Description AS PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION
FROM Orders
GROUP BY PRODUCT_SKU,PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION
ORDER BY PRODUCT_SALES_NUMBER DESC 
LIMIT 9) ord1 JOIN (
SELECT COUNT(*) AS RETURNED_AMOUNT, Orders.SKU AS PRODUCT_SKU, Orders.Description AS PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION
FROM Orders INNER JOIN RMA ON Orders.OrderID = RMA.OrderID
WHERE UPPER(Status) = "COMPLETE"
GROUP BY PRODUCT_SKU,PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION) ord2 ON ord1.PRODUCT_SKU = ord2.PRODUCT_SKU
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the numbers in DESC order, I added the following line to the bottom:
ORDER BY PRODUCT_SALES_NUMBER - RETURNED_AMOUNT DESC;

So the whole script looks like:

```
SELECT
    PRODUCT_SALES_NUMBER - RETURNED_AMOUNT, ord1.PRODUCT_SKU, ord1.PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION
FROM
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS PRODUCT_SALES_NUMBER, Orders.SKU AS PRODUCT_SKU, Orders.Description AS PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION
        FROM Orders
        GROUP BY PRODUCT_SKU, PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION 
        ORDER BY PRODUCT_SALES_NUMBER DESC
        LIMIT 20
    ) ord1 JOIN (
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS RETURNED_AMOUNT, Orders.SKU AS PRODUCT_SKU, Orders.Description AS PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION
        FROM Orders INNER JOIN RMA ON Orders.OrderID = RMA.OrderID
        WHERE UPPER(Status) = 'COMPLETE' OR UPPER(Status) = 'Initiated' OR UPPER(Status) = 'Pending'
        GROUP BY PRODUCT_SKU, PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION
    ) ord2 ON ord1.PRODUCT_SKU = ord2.PRODUCT_SKU
ORDER BY PRODUCT_SALES_NUMBER - RETURNED_AMOUNT DESC;
```